# How to pass extra data in passport-facebook authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to write an web application in `Node.js` which uses `passport-facebook` authentication strategy. By default the mechanism provided in the example works by redirecting user to `Facebook API` where user can put there username and password to login. Once Facebook verifies the user, it passes the token back to a callback URL in my application.

Now these things works for my application. I can login using Facebook with no problem. But I want one extra field to be passed to the server when I try to login.

Basically my plan is to add a `TextField` and a `Login Button` in my homepage. After successful login, when the callback function is executed, I want to capture the value of `TextField` from this callback. Is there any way of doing that? Any help is highly appreciated.

This is the body of my HTML page

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <p>Login or Register with:</p>
            <a href="/auth/facebook" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my `nod.js` code:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect :   '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect :   '/'
}));

app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard.ejs', {
        user : {
            name : req.user.facebook.name,
            profilePic : req.user.facebook.profilePic
        }
    });
});
```

Basically I just want to add an extra `TextField` just before my `LogIn` button. And from the `/dashboard` route, I want to get the value of that `TextField`. So my code for `/dashboard` will look something like this:

```
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard.ejs', {
        user : {
            role:   VALUE_FROM_TEXT_FIELD,
            name : req.user.facebook.name,
            profilePic : req.user.facebook.profilePic
        }
    });
});
```

So I have a twofold question:
1. How to pass this `TextField` value from the frontend. Should it be inside a `Form` or what?
2. How do I capture the value of the `TextField` inside the `/dashboard` route?

Comment: Can you give some example of your work ? I suspect you should be able to use the callback url to passback this

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a custom callback instead of the standard Passport.js one?

An example for the 'local' strategy is:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

You should be able to pass in the additional value in the request and handle it in the callback.

**EDIT: For your particular scenario, you're probably looking at something along the lines of this...**

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
            // let the next route handler do its thing...
            // or you can handle the error yourself within this
            // callback.
        }

        // if the user returns as nothing (doesn't exist) then redirect
        if (!user) {
            // this takes the place of failureRedirect
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err); // again - on error, 'next' depending on your requirement.
            }
            // this takes the place of successRedirect
            return res.redirect('/dashboard');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Hopefully this clarifies :)

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you tell me how I can get the data in my given scenario? I was able to use a custom callback like your example, and can get the data from req object. But for my example I need the data after login is successful.

Comment: Updated. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Apologies. Just realised I have missed the point of what you're doing. Can you share how you are configuring the Strategy?

ie. passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(..)

Answer (score 0):

What i did is pass a custom function instead of using sucessRedirect and pass it the variable need. In my case it was req.session.backurl which was used to send them back to the page which they needed to be authenticated to access.

```
users.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
         //req.session.backURL||
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),function(req,res){
res.redirect(req.session.backURL||'/'); //custom function used instead of sucessRedirect

});
```